# Is there a programatic way to access iTunesConnect sales reports?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've got an app on the iTunes store, and Apple provides daily (and weekly) sales reports.  I'd like to download these in an automated fashion (say, via script attached to a cron job), but I'm not sure how to get around all their https-forms, Web-objects controls, session-IDs, etc.

Does anyone have a plug & play solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a thread in the Dev Forums about this: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/1253?start=0&tstart=0'>Sales Reports Script

Link: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/1253?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to find someone had done it before I went & reinvented the wheel...   :)

Answer (score 1):

I really like AppSales, an open-source iPhone app that scrapes the iTunes Connect website and gives you daily and weekly reports, graphs etc. It's open source so you can extend it to your needs.

http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

Answer (score 0):

There's no API but you cant "scrape" it, there are various open source scripts online.

Instead though you can use [www.appfigures.com](http://www.appfigures.com) which downloads reports automatically, turns them into interactive sales/downloads reports and sends parsed reports by email automatically as well as shows your reviews from all 77 app stores around the world and rank trending from 6 major app stores.

For security reasons I'd use a sub iTC account when signing up.

And its completely free (while in beta)